# Fixed color for specific value

Tags: r, colors

I am trying to make a temperature map, all works fine but I don't know how to have a fixed color palette.

Actually I have this :

```
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","yellow","orange","red"), 
                                space = "Lab")

image.plot(akima.smooth, 
           col = rgb.palette(NBR.COLORS), 
           main=main_title, 
           horizontal=TRUE,
           axes=TRUE)
```

This solution works but the colors which are painted are always from blue to red.

For example if the lowest temperature on the map is -10°C the color will be blue, but in another map if the lowest temperature is +25°C that color will be blue too.

How can I define a fixed color panel such as :

```
-30°C => blue
-20°C => light blue
-10°C => dark green
  0°C => green
 10°C => yellow
```

If in map 1 lowest temperature is -20 I want "light blue" and in map 2 if lowest temperature is 10°C I want "yellow" color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this solution :

```
col = colorRampPalette(c("darkmagenta","blue","green","yellow","orange","red"),
                       space="Lab")(NBR.COLORS) 
breaks = c(seq(-35, 10, length.out=NBR.COLORS/2), 10, 
           seq(10, 35, length.out=NBR.COLORS/2))
image.plot(akima.smooth, col=col, breaks=breaks, main=main_title,
           horizontal=TRUE,axes=TRUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is `fields:::image.plot()` then see the arguments to function `?image`. In particular the `breaks` argument is required to set the values for the boundaries of the cut points used to break the input data into the classes for plotting.

The problem you are seeing is that if you don't set `breaks` then the colour palette is being applied to the *range* of the input data. If you set `breaks` then the colour palette is mapped across the full range you want and the data allocated to the groups, and hence the colours, defined by the break points.

I haven't included an example in case this is not `fields:::image.plot()`

Comment: @user1311058 Glad it worked. Make sure to accept your Answer when you can so as to indicate this Q&A was successfully concluded. It helps others know a problem was solved. See the [How Do I Ask Questions Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) part of the FAQ.

Comment: @user1311058 Thanks for the accept but your Answer is the more complete one and deserving of the accept. You can do this after a day (or so?) of posting your own Answer. I won't be offended if you deselect mine and accept yours later; the aim is to provide the best resource for programming on the web.