# creating comparable heatmaps in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to create 2 heatmaps with variable values in R. I would like the colors and values to be scaled so that the values of the two heatmaps will be comparable. Right now I am using the heatmap.2 from the gplot package.

```
MyHeatMap <- heatmap.2(MyData, trace="none", col=greenred)
```

My data is in the from of a numeric matrix. I have two of these matrices where the numeric ranges of the values are slightly different and I would like to create quality heatmaps for both (does not have to necessarily be using the sample package).

Comment: Define what you mean by "quality" and clarify whether it is desired that the same numeric value in both matrices should produce the same color on these heatmaps.

Comment: @DWin:I've tried some other heatmap functions using other packages such as made4 where the data was all scaled automatically but the resulting heatmaps did not have much color variation (seemed mostly monotone green and red). I would like the same numeric value in both matrices to have the same color in both heatmaps.

Comment: I don't have gplots installed, but perhaps [the strategy demonstrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436091/fixed-color-for-specific-value) will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've encountered this issue a number of times in my own analyses and here is how I would suggest handling it.

Firstly, set your greenred color variable to have 256 colors with greenred(256).

Then, create a break variable that contains the range of numbers that you would like to split these 256 colors on for both heatmaps (the length will be one more than the length of the color vector). So, for instance, if you wanted the spread to be from -1 to 1 from green to red, respectively, you would do

```
pairs.breaks = seq(from=-1,to=1,length.out=257)
```

Then, when calling your heatmaps, use

```
MyHeatMap1 <- heatmap.2(MyData1, trace="none", col=greenred(256), breaks=pairs.breaks)
MyHeatMap2 <- heatmap.2(MyData2, trace="none", col=greenred(256), breaks=pairs.breaks)
```

This should produce two heat maps with different data sets that use identical color scales.

Hope this helps!

Ron

Comment: Beautifully simple solution!